# React Firebase make new Collection on button click

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hellooo ! I would like to make a chatroom (similar to Instagram) in my app. I'm working with react and Firebase and now I'm wondering how to write a function that makes ChatRoom2, ChatRoom3, etc. when you click on the "Add Chat" button?
I figured the best way to structure the db is to go with this structure :

```
ChatRooms (collection)
  ChatRoom1 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      ...
  ChatRoom2 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      ...
```

But I'm not sure how to write the function.

Comment: The [documentation on adding documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) is quite thorough, what specifically is causing you trouble? Or is your query, how to create the collection at the same time as the new chat room document?

Comment: How to create the collection at the same time as the new chat room document @samthecodingman

Comment: The collection will be created at the same time you add a document to the collection. There is no extra action to be done, just add a doc to the (non-existing) collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a collection you just need to add a document in that `CollectionReference`.

```js
// The button to create new chat
<button onClick={createNewChat}>

const createNewChat = async () => {
  const newChatDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, "ChatRooms"), {
    ...newChatFields
  });

  const firstMsgDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, "ChatRooms", newChatDoc.id, "messages"), {
    content: "Welcome to Chat."
  });

  console.log(`New chat created: ${newChatDoc.id}`)
}
```